# Convert enum from object to long without a try block?

Tags: c#, object, enums, .net

Follow along in my test source. What is a good way to get a value from a enum object? Must support long. I am attempting without a try/catch block.

```
enum ELong: long { a = 0x100000000 };
enum ENormal { a = 25 }

        var l = (object) ELong.a;
        var n = (object)ENormal.a;
        //will cast into the correct size
        int ii = (int)n; //ok
        long ll = (long)l; //ok
        //wont cast if its too big
        ll = (long)n; //cast exception
        //or too small
        n = (int)l; //cast exception//compile error. Cannot cast
        //lets try preventing the exception with is
        if (n is int)
            ii = (int)n;//doesnt get here.
        if (n is long)
            ll = (long)n;//doesnt get here.
        if (l is int)
            ii = (int)l;//doesnt get here
        if (l is long)
            ll = (long)l;//doesnt get here
        //WHY!!!!
        //Maybe as will do the trick?
        if (n as int? != null)
            ii = (int)n;//doesnt get here.
        if (n as long? != null)
            ll = (long)n;//doesnt get here.
        if (l as int? != null)
            ii = (int)l;//doesnt get here
        if (l as long? != null)
            ll = (long)l;//doesnt get here
        //geez. What is more stange is (int) will work while (int?) will not
        int? ni = (int?)n;//cast exception
        int iii = (int)n; //works
        ll = (long)n;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Explanation**

```
if (n is int)
        ii = (int)n;//doesnt get here.
    if (n is long)
        ll = (long)n;//doesnt get here.
    if (l is int)
        ii = (int)l;//doesnt get here
    if (l is long)
        ll = (long)l;//doesnt get here
```

*n* and *l* is neither *int/long* nor *long?/int?*, they are of type of your enum, so this is expected behavior.

**Solution**

Probably you should use *Convert* class to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 6):

```
long test1 = Convert.ToInt64(l); // 4294967296
long test2 = Convert.ToInt64(n); // 25
```

Comment: Convert.ToInt64 will throw exception. What about Int64.TryParse method

Comment: argh, i wonder what the convert class does behind the scenes. Hopefully not a normal cast inside a try block. But that would make sense. -edit- ThinkJet answered it. I can guess what ChangeType may do.

Comment: Adeel: I tried it, it works fine as long as it is a enum. I would want an exception if i somehow allowed the object to not be an enum or Value type.

Answer (score 3):

Example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getunderlyingtype.aspx):

```
static object GetAsUnderlyingType(Enum enval)
{
    Type entype = enval.GetType();

    Type undertype = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(entype);

    return Convert.ChangeType( enval, undertype );
}
```

1. Convert to underlying type (int or long)
2. Cast converted value to your variable (I guess simple assign result to long variable).

Comment: It's gonna be pretty slow, but that is what I am using as well. (If I can't help myself otherwise)